# My code can't find the file

Tags: python

I have written a program that has to execute a file and draw it in turtle.
But when I try to call a fdl filename it cant find it.

```
import turtle

#I start out making the basic turtle commands

def lt (turtle, n):
    turtle.lt(n)

def fd (turtle, n):
    turtle.fd(n)

def bk (turtle, n):
    turtle.bk(n)

def rt (turtle, n):
    turtle.rt(n)

#Then i create a class that makes it possible to create a set of rules

class Rule(object):
    #Here the rule based on a description string is initialized like ("F -> F L F L")

    def __init__(self,repr):
        #This is where the left and right part of the rule in "F -> F L F L" comes in
        self.left, self.right = [a.strip() for a in repr.split("->")]

        if self.left is None or self.right is None:
            print("Invalid rule description!")

    #Now i use the same princip like i did in task6. the Apply function
    def apply_rule_on_elements(self,element):
        return [self._apply_rule_for_element (element) for element in elements]

    #This is a helper function that only works on one element at a time
    def _apply_rule_for_element (self,element):
        if element == self.left:
            return self.right.split()
        return element

#Here is a very simple helper function, handy in some cases
#This allows one to perform assignment multiple values og grouping

def split_command(command, *args):
    return command, args

#Now i make a command class that wraps the execution of a given command
class Command(object):
    def __init__(self,command):
        #the name and number of arguments for the given command
        self.name,self.args = split_command(*command.split())

    def execute(self,turtle,length):
        if self.name == "lt":
            lt(turtle,int(self.args[0]))
        elif self.name == "scale":
            length[0] = length[0]*float(self.args[0])
        elif self.name == "fd":
            fd(turtle,length[0])
        elif self.name == "bk":
            bk(turtle,length[0])
        elif self.name == "rt":
            rt(turtle,int(self.args[0]))
        elif self.name == "nop":
            pass

#Here i write the main Fractal class
class Fractal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #Initial and current state
        self.state = []

        #Rules associated with the current fractal
        self.rules = []

        #Commands associated with the current fractal
        self.commands = {}

        #since values are immutable and passed by value, I use an array (passed by reference value)
        #to allow the modification of the variable
        self.length = [0]

        #The current depth
        self.depth = 0

    #Executes the command associated w/ the current states stored in the fractal
    def execute_commands(self,turtle,states):
        for state in states:
            self.commands[state].execute(turtle,self.length)

    #Flattens a list
    def _flatten(self,l):
        flattened_list = []
        for element in l:
            flattened_list.extend(element)
        return flattened_list

    #Here i compute the fractal, which does that actual iteration work
    #It returns the state of the fractal after the computation
    def compute(self):
        current_depth = self.depth
        current_state = self.state

        while self.depth !=0:
            current_state=self.compute_next_state(current_state)
            self.depth-=1

        return current_state

    def _compute_next_state(self,state):
        for rule in self.rules:
            state = rule.apply_rule_on_elements(state)
        return self._flatten(state)

#This parses the fdl file, creates a fractal and set it up with the values 
#read in the fdl file
def read_fdl(filename):
    import os

    f = Fractal()

    if os.path.exists(filename):
        lines = open(filename).readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if not len(line.strip())==0:
                name,arguments = split_command(*line.strip().split())

                if name == "start":
                    f.state = arguments
                elif name == "rule":
                    f.rules.append(Rule("".join(arguments)))
                elif name =="length":
                    f.length = [int(arguments[0])]
                elif name == "depth":
                    f.depth = int(arguments[0])
                elif name == "cmd":
                    f.commands[arguments[0]] = Command("".join (arguments[1:]))
    else:
        print("File does not exist")

    #no check is made, to see if we have a fractal that was completely initialized

    return f

import sys
import turtle

if len(sys.argv)>1:
    f=read_fdl(sys.argv[1])
    f.execute_commands(turtle,f.compute())

read_fdl("sierpinski")
```

The message I get is `"File does not exist"`, but it does.

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mcve].

Comment: `os.path.exists("sierpinski")` says it doesn't exist. Specify the complete path and/or add the file's extension.

Comment: Use absolute path of the file

Comment: i already made sure that the file is in the same folder.

Comment: What does it mean **same**? Same as *what*?

Comment: alternatively, `sys.argv` is longer than 1 and it's trying to open whatever you're passing on the command line. Either way, the file doesn't exist as specified. `sierpinksi.txt` is not the same as `sierpinkski` is not the same as `/home/joachim/sierpinski.turtle`.

Comment: the same folder as the file im running is in

Comment: I was surprised you could "have written a program" so polished without having opened a data file for input during testing or development.  Then I discovered your program is [identical to one in the Appendix of this page](https://www.scribd.com/document/90769681/Fractal-and-the-Beauty-of-Nature) except for the code comments.  Perhaps that page can give you some insight on how to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it doesn't exist** - at least not **in the current directory** and **without an extension**.

Try adding the **right directory** and **extension** to the name `"sierpinski"`

Comment: That means using the absolute path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is an fdl (fractal definition language) file, try:

```
read_fdl("sierpinski.fdl")
```